# Python 3 - Merge nested result into one list

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-loops

I have a nested loop that results in a structure of lists of variable number of lines, and i want to merge them all in a single list. The problem is that, when i try to append the lists, It appends only the number of iterations from the previous loop, and not all the result lines at once.

This is the code below:

```
PNL = sock.execute(dbname,uid,pwd,'product.template','search',[('product_variant_ids', '=', SOLid)])
for PNLid in PNL:
    Pname = sock.execute(dbname,uid,pwd,'product.template','read',PNLid)
    Pname = Pname[0]
    Pname = Pname['bom_ids']

    BoM = sock.execute(dbname,uid,pwd,'mrp.bom.line','search',[('bom_id','=',Pname)])
    for BoMs in BoM:
        RAWnames = sock.execute(dbname,uid,pwd,'mrp.bom.line','read',BoMs)
        RAWnames = RAWnames[0]
        LdM = RAWnames['product_id'][1], RAWnames['product_qty'], RAWnames['x_studio_custo_unitrio']
        BoM0 = list(LdM)
        print(BoM0)
```

And this is the resulting lines of lists.:

```
['Material 1', 1.0, 1.0]
['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0]
['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0]
['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0]
['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0]
['Material 4', 4.0, 4.0]
```

I need to transform these into a single list. Like below, but i'm really not sure how.

```
[['Material 1', 1.0, 1.0],
['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0],
['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0],
['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0],
['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0],
['Material 4', 4.0, 4.0]]
```

So, for example, if the first for loop iterates two times, when i append, i get two lists like below, but it can loop more often.:

```
[['Material 1', 1.0, 1.0], ['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0], ['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0]]
[['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0], ['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0], ['Material 4', 4.0, 4.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make an "overall container" outside of your looping structure.  And after you have constructed one of the elements, append it to that list.

```
# make a container for results OUTSIDE of your looping structure
result = []

for i in range(3):
    for name in (['bob', 'cindy', 'dave']):
        temp = [i, name]
        result.append(temp)


print(result)
```

#### result

```
[[0, 'bob'], [0, 'cindy'], [0, 'dave'], [1, 'bob'], [1, 'cindy'], [1, 'dave'], [2, 'bob'], [2, 'cindy'], [2, 'dave']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I still get two lines as a result. But at least now, the last line is the complete result i was expecting. Maybe if i could suppress the lines before the last one... This is the result:
[['Material 1', 1.0, 1.0], ['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0], ['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0]]
[['Material 1', 1.0, 1.0], ['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0], ['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0], ['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0], ['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0], ['Material 4', 4.0, 4.0]]

Comment: Solved! I just add to unindent the 'print'. Thank you so much!